# How to create .plist file under /Library/LaunchAgents

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd, launch-agent

I'm trying to develop a launch agent for macOS via Apple Doc

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

One of my requirements is that the agent should work for all users. What I understood from above document is I have to put my .plist under "/Library/LaunchAgents" folder.

When I try to create this file programatically nothing happens with the below code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[plist setObject:@"test" forKey: @"test 1"];
NSString *userLaunchAgentsPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",  @"/Library/LaunchAgents/com.xxx.agent.plist"];
    [plist writeToFile:userLaunchAgentsPath atomically:YES];
```

Probably the reason is a privilege issue. Do you have any ideas for solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As to privileges, the plist should be owned by root and if you want the app to run as a different user, you can do that easily by providing the username/password in the plist. Your app is probably not running as root.

Comment: http://www.launchd.info For me path is not important, my point how i can create .plist file under /Library/LaunchAgents or /Library/LaunchDaemons.

Comment: Since as my answer mentions the file has to be owned by root, unless you are authenticating as root, or your app is running as root, there's your solution, right?

Comment: So you are thinking people will install this app and then the app will setup the daemon. Is that realistic? I know wanting your users to make a launchctl file seems like it's asking for trouble, but it's also unlikely that they will want a strange application getting root access. So I think the answer here is to ship a launchctl file with your app that has most the fields filled in, then give them instructions for adding it.

Comment: This requirement was not from me, anyway i m going to talk with my manager. Thank you.

Comment: @Rob means it's not possible to create daemon (.plist) from the macOS app?